# "samples" option yields empty graph with addplot3 and gnuplot contour (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, gnuplot

The following code plots the desired level set :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel={$x$},
    xmin=-400,xmax=400,
    ymin=-.2,ymax=.2,
    view={0}{90},
    }}

\begin{axis}[mystyle]
  \addplot3[contour gnuplot={levels={.5},labels=false},domain=-400:400] {.5*y^2-cos(x)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Nevertheless, the output is extremely coarse. I therefore tried to refine the level set by adding the option `samples=100` in the following way:

```
  \addplot3[contour gnuplot={levels={.5},labels=false},domain=-400:400,samples=100] 
      {.5*y^2-cos(x)};
```

Unfortunately, doing so makes the level set disappear.

Do you know why, and even more importantly how to refine the curve?

PS : I cannot upload the output of the codes because of my reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As understood by JLDiaz,

> the domain for y will be also [-400,400] and in this range the function y^2 takes very large values which will cause floating point rounding errors.

The solution I used was to manually convert degrees to radians. The result became relevant. Of course the tick labels also changed, which can be adjusted if needed.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
 ylabel={$y$},
xlabel={$x$},
xmin=-400*pi/180,xmax=400*pi/180,
ymin=-4,ymax=4,
view={0}{90},
}}

\begin{axis}[mystyle]
\addplot3[,contour gnuplot={levels={.5},labels=false},domain=-400*pi/180:400*pi/180,samples=50] {.5*y^2-cos(x*180/pi)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of what's going on here. When you use an even number of samples, the output is empty. If you use instead an odd number of samples, you get results. However the results is different depending on the number of samples used.

**samples=25**

[image: 25]

**samples=45**

[image: 45]

**samples=65**

[image: 65]

I guess that these problems are related to the huge range you use. In the domain [-400,400] for x there are a lot of periods for the function `cos(x)`, so if you don't have enough sampling points aliasing artifacts are to be expected. Also, by default the domain for y will be also [-400,400] and in this range the function y^2 takes very large values which will cause floating point rounding errors.

If you specify a shorter range for y, you get better and consistent results. But also they are very different from the ones you got with y domain [-400:400]. Indeed, I had to change the y axis to show from -5 to 5 to fit the result, but I guess that these results are more correct than the previous ones.

These are the results for `y domain=-10:10`

**samples=25**

[image: 25 good]

**samples=45**

[image: 45 good]

**samples=65**

[image: 65 good]

This is the code I used to produce the three last figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel={$x$},
    xmin=-400,xmax=400,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    view={0}{90},
    }}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[mystyle]
\addplot3[contour gnuplot={levels={.5},labels=false},
      domain=-400:400, y domain=-10:10, samples=25 ] {.5*y^2-cos(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mystyle]
\addplot3[contour gnuplot={levels={.5},labels=false},
      domain=-400:400, y domain=-10:10, samples=45 ] {.5*y^2-cos(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mystyle]
\addplot3[contour gnuplot={levels={.5},labels=false},
      domain=-400:400, y domain=-10:10, samples=65 ] {.5*y^2-cos(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, which led me to a working solution. I don't agree with you remark *[-400,400] for x there are a lot of periods for the function cos(x)* but I know think the correct explanation is what comes next: * by default the domain for y will be also [-400,400] and in this range the function y^2 takes very large values which will cause floating point rounding errors*.

Comment: [too long editing...] Thank you so much for your answer, which led me to a working solution. I don't agree with your remark **[-400,400] for x there are a lot of periods for the function cos(x)** (because it seems I'm in degrees) but I know think the correct explanation is what comes next: **by default the domain for y will be also [-400,400] and in this range the function y^2 takes very large values which will cause floating point rounding errors**.

The final solution I used was to (manually) convert degrees in radians, i.e. change `cos(x)` to `cos(180*x/pi)`, and the limits accordingly.

Comment: I'd like to publish the working code, according to your comments. How can I do so without having to accept *my* answer?

Comment: @anderstood You can post an answer to your own question, of course. Also you can accept it or not, as you prefer. You can also edit the original question adding a section "Update" to show your working solution.

Comment: I accepted my own answer based on yours, hoping you do not care too much about your reputation points... ! [edit: I'll accept it when I can]